# Ubuntu fails on certain DNS lookups

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system

I have a dual boot system running Vista and Ubuntu. There are certain DNS lookups that don't work on ubuntu (chat.freenode.net, releases.mozilla.org and the YIM server to name a few).

All these work correctly when I boot Vista. ATM I'm just getting someone else to find the IP address for me and adding that to my /etc/hosts . Once that's done, it works fine.

I can't test other Linux distributions, as they're united in their hatred of either my graphics card or my network card.

So my question, Is this a known issue (hopefully with a known fix)? If not, is there any more efficient way to get the IP address other than asking someone to get it for me?

(And I'd like to remind people, before someone tags it belongs-on-superuser, that superuser does not yet exist)

Comment: Do you use the same DNS servers in Ubuntu and Vista? (and I think you meant /etc/hosts and not /etc/resolv.conf)

Comment: Yes, it's the same DNS servers. And sorry, I did mean /etc/hosts.

Comment: Post your `/etc/resolve.conf` and `nslookup chat.freenode.net` output, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In previous Ubuntu versions [AVAHI http://avahi.org/wiki/AvahiAndUnicastDotLocal](http://avahi.org/wiki/AvahiAndUnicastDotLocal) caused DNS problems.  Click on the link and see if this may be your problem.

Apparently, I can't post URLS.  So here's the link http://avahi.org/wiki/AvahiAndUnicastDotLocal